# SVN: workflow of importing existing project to a new rep

Tags: svn

I can't wrap my ahead around one step you have to do after you import your already existing project (already working code, etc.) into a new repository.

Everything goes like this:

1. **svnadmin create** C:/Reps/MillionDollarApp
2. **svn import** C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp file:///C:/Reps/MillionDollarApp -m "Initial import"

Now, the code from C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp sits in its repository, however, SVN still does not tracks the code inside C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp.

How do you do that?
 How to start tracking project's code you just imported?

Do you delete everything from C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp and checkout from repository?
Do you checkout without deleting the code? These two solutions feels just wrong.

Most tutorials/examples goes like this:

1. Create new repo
2. Import from existing project (ex, c:/code)
3. Checkout to another place (ex., c:/code2)
4. Work with code you just checkouted (c:/code2) (what do you do with code in c:/code ????)

But in my situation I need:

1. Create new repo
2. Import from existing project (c:/code)
3. **?????**
4. Work and use version control features with the same code (c:/code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`svn import` doesn't make a working copy.  You will need to do an `svn checkout`.  Is there some reason you cannot delete `c:\code` an then checkout a new working copy there?  If there is, some things are missing from svn and/or not well with your project.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:

1. Create new repo at `C:/Reps/MillionDollarApp`
2. Check out at `C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp`
3. Commit

... and then start working. Some Subversion clients (such as TortoiseSVN) will warn you about the checkout folder not being empty but you can proceed anyway: since the repository is empty you should not lose any of your unversioned files.

This assumes that you aren't using the standard trunk/branches/tags structures. If you want it, you'll need to create the appropriate folders (it can be done directly on the repository) and check out from e.g. `trunk`.

Whatever, I wouldn't feel confortable if that's the only copy of my code. I normally do as follows:

1. Rename `C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp` as `C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp.orig`
2. Create new repo at `C:/Reps/MillionDollarApp`
3. Check out at `C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp`
4. Move `C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp.orig` into `C:/myCode/MillionDollarApp`
5. Commit

I find it more intuitive that the `import` command because I can preview all changes.